# Prevent paging on custom "batch edit" radgrid if changes haven't been saved

Tags: telerik, radgrid, custom-paging

We have a pretty customized "batch edit" type screen. Out users frequently make changes, then forget to hit Save before moving on to the next page. I have tried the solutions found here:
[a link] http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/prevent-losing-batch-editing-changes-on-paging-or-any-other-postback

[a link] http://www.telerik.com/forums/prevent-losing-batch-editing-changes-on-paging-or-any-other-postback

But I end up with errors like "RecordNumber" is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation. Here's my code.  I'm thinking our grid is just too complicated for these straightforward solutions...?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="AssignTeacherAdvisor2.aspx.cs" Inherits="AssignTeacherAdvisor2" Theme="LBL" %>

<%@ Register Src="Controls/ActionBar.ascx" TagName="ActionBar" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMainAppTop" runat="Server">
    <div id="populateTchrIDs" runat="server">

<%--        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function KGCalChange(sender, eventArgs) {
                //debugger;
                if (sender.value == "KG") {
                    showHideLayer('<%= labelKGCal_Search.ClientID %>', 'show');
                    showHideLayer('<%= comboKGCal_Search.ClientID %>', 'show');
                }
                else {
                    showHideLayer('<%= labelKGCal_Search.ClientID %>', 'hide');
                    showHideLayer('<%= comboKGCal_Search.ClientID %>', 'hide');
                }
            }
        </script>--%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function clientItemChecking(sender, args) 
    {
        if (sender.get_checkedItems().length == 3 && (args.get_item().get_checked() == false))
        {
        alert("count exceeded");
        args.set_cancel(true);
        }
    }
    function clientItemCheckingC(sender, args) {
        if (sender.get_checkedItems().length == 5 && (args.get_item().get_checked() == false)) {
            alert("count exceeded");
            args.set_cancel(true);
        }
    }
</script>
    </div>
    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server">
        <uc1:ActionBar ID="ActionBarTop" runat="server" CancelVisible="True" ExportVisible="True"
            SaveVisible="True" Text="Assign Teacher/Advisor" HelpVisible="True" ExportURL="~/DataExport.aspx?frm=AssignTeacherAdvisor2"
            OnSaveClick="ActionBar_SaveClick" OnCancelClick="ActionBar_CancelClick" />
        <table class="six" style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="padded header">
                        Search and Sort
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkAdvancedSearch" runat="server" NavigateUrl="javascript:ToggleAdvanced();"
                        class="advancedSearchLink">
                        Advanced Search</asp:HyperLink> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenField" runat="server" />
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelSaveSuccess" runat="server" CssClass="infoMessage" Visible="false">
            <asp:Label ID="LabelSaveSuccess" runat="server" Text="Information saved successfully." />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummaryMain" runat="server" />
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" Display="None" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"></asp:CustomValidator>
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelInputs" runat="server" DefaultButton="WebButtonSearch">
            <table class="eight" style="width: 100%">
            <tr><td colspan = "8" style="text-align: right;">
                        <sis:InputLabel ID="lblRunReport" runat="server" Text="Report:" Visible="False" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlRunReport" runat="server" Width="160px" Visible="False" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBoxReport_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <CollapseAnimation Duration="200" Type="OutQuint" />
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                        <sis:WebButton ID="wbtnRunReport" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/LBL/wbtnRunReport.gif"
                            AutoTipKey="Run Report" UseCssHover="True" OnClick="wbtnRunReport_Click" Visible="False" />
                </td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="start">
                    <sis:InputLabel ID="lblLastName_Search" runat="server" Text="Last Name:" />
                </td>
                <td class="start data">
                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtLastName_Search" runat="server">
                    </telerik:RadTextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="start">
                    <sis:InputLabel ID="lblFirstName_Search" runat="server" Text="First Name:" />
                </td>
                <td class="start data">
                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtFirstName_Search" runat="server">
                    </telerik:RadTextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="start">
                    <sis:InputLabel ID="lblGrades_Search" runat="server" Text="Grade Level:"></sis:InputLabel>
                </td> 
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="lstGrades_Search" runat="server" CheckBoxes="true" EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="true" Width ="100px"  ></telerik:RadComboBox> 
                    <asp:Literal ID="Literal3" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td class="end">
                    <sis:InputLabel ID="lblTeacherAssigned_Search" runat="server" Text="Teacher Assigned:" />
                </td>
                <td class="end data">
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbTeacherAssigned_Search" runat="server" Width="75px">
                        <Items>
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Selected="True" Text="   " />
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Yes" Value="Yes" />
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="No" Value="No" />
                        </Items>
                        <CollapseAnimation Duration="200" Type="OutQuint" />
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </td>
            </table>
            <table class="six" style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="start">
<%--                        <div id="labelKGCal_Search" runat="server">
                            <sis:InputLabel ID="lblKGCal_Search" runat="server" Text="KG Calendar:" />
                        </div>--%>
                    </td>
                    <td class="start data">
<%--                        <div id="comboKGCal_Search" runat="server" style="width: 301px">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbKGCal_Search" runat="server" Width="249px" Height="31px">
                                <CollapseAnimation Duration="200" Type="OutQuint" />
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>--%>
                    </td>
                    <td class="end">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="end data">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="DivAdvancedSearch" class="advancedSearch" runat="server">
                <table class="eight" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="start">
                            <sis:InputLabel ID="lblCurrentYearTeacher_Search" runat="server" Text="Current Year Teacher/Advisor:"></sis:InputLabel>
                        </td> 
                        <td>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="lstCurrentYearTeacher_Search" runat="server" CheckBoxes="true" EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="false" Width ="250px" OnClientItemChecking="clientItemCheckingC" ></telerik:RadComboBox> 
                            <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="start">
                            <sis:InputLabel ID="lblPriorYearTeacher_Search" runat="server" Text="Prior Year Teacher/Advisor:"></sis:InputLabel>
                        </td> 
                        <td>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="lstPriorYearTeacher_Search" runat="server" CheckBoxes="true" EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="false" Width ="250px" OnClientItemChecking="clientItemCheckingC"></telerik:RadComboBox> 
                            <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="start">
                            <sis:InputLabel ID="lblGender" runat="server" Text="Gender:"></sis:InputLabel>
                        </td>
                        <td class="start data">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbGender_Search" runat="server" Width="85px">
                                <Items>
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Selected="True" Text="  " />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Male" Value="Male" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Female" Value="Female" />
                                </Items>
                                <CollapseAnimation Duration="200" Type="OutQuint" />
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="end">
                            <sis:InputLabel ID="lblRowsToDisplay_Search" runat="server" Text="Rows to Display:" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="end data">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbRowsToDisplay_Search" runat="server" Width="65px">
                                <Items>
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="10" Value="10" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="20" Value="20" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="30" Value="30" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="50" Value="50" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="100" Value="100" />
                                </Items>
                                <CollapseAnimation Duration="200" Type="OutQuint" />
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="start">
                            <sis:InputLabel ID="lblFlags_Search" runat="server" Text="Flags (up to 3):"></sis:InputLabel>
                        </td> 
                        <td>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="lstFlags_Search" runat="server" CheckBoxes="true" EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="false" Width ="250px" OnClientItemChecking="clientItemChecking"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                            <asp:Literal ID="itemsClientSide" runat="server" />
                        </td>

                        <td class="start">
                            <sis:InputLabel ID="lblIncludeFlag_Search" runat="server" Text="Include Flag:"></sis:InputLabel>
                        </td>
                        <td class="start data">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbIncludeFlag_Search" runat="server" Width="85px">
                                <Items>
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Selected="True" Text=" " />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="All Flags" Value="A" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="One or more" Value="O" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="None of These" Value="N" />
                                </Items>
                                <CollapseAnimation Duration="200" Type="OutQuint" />
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="start">
                            <sis:InputLabel ID="InputLabelCY" runat="server" Text="Cohort Year:" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="start data" align="left" style="width: 138px">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBoxCY_Search" runat="server" TabIndex="4" Width="100px">
                                <CollapseAnimation Duration="200" Type="OutQuint" />
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="end">
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td class="end data">
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="width: 100%" class="six">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 121px" class="start" valign="top">
                            <sis:InputLabel ID="lblDOBFrom_Search" runat="server" Text="DOB Range - From:"></sis:InputLabel>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 99px" class="start data" valign="top">
                            <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dateDOBFrom_Search" runat="server" Width="100px">
                                <DateInput InvalidStyleDuration="100">
                                </DateInput>
                            </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" style="width: 37px" class="start" valign="top">
                            <sis:InputLabel ID="lblDOBTo_Search" runat="server" Text="To:"></sis:InputLabel>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" style="width: 113px" class="start data" valign="top">
                            <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dateDOBTo_Search" runat="server" Width="100px">
                                <DateInput InvalidStyleDuration="100">
                                </DateInput>
                            </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <table class="eight" style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <sis:WebButton ID="WebButtonSearch" runat="server" UseCssHover="true" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/LBL/wbtnSearch.gif"
                            AutoTipKey="Search" OnClick="WebButtonSearch_Click" AllowLoadBox="True" />
                        <sis:WebButton ID="WebButtonReset" runat="server" UseCssHover="true" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/LBL/wbtnReset.gif"
                            AutoTipKey="Reset" OnClick="WebButtonReset_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <asp:Label ID="lblReturnExceedMax" runat="server" CssClass="ListPageStatus"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldAdvanced" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <div class="hr">
            <hr />
        </div>
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="left" style="width: 90px">
                    <div id="totals" class="padded header" style="width: 93px">
                        Students
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <sis:WebButton ID="WebButtonTotals" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/LBL/wbtnViewTotals.gif"
                        AutoTipKey="View totals" OnClick="WebButtonTotals_Click" UseCssHover="true" />
                </td>
                <td><sis:WebButton ID="WebButtonVerify" runat="server" 
                        ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/LBL/wbtnVerify.gif" AutoTipKey="Verify" onclick="WebButtonVerify_Click" 
                        UseCssHover="True" AlertEnabled="True" AlertIcon="Question" 
                        AlertText="You have requested to verify Teacher/Advisor assignments.  Would you like to continue?" 
                        AlertTitle="Verify" /></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="grdResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            AllowCustomPaging="True" AllowPaging="True" OnNeedDataSource="grdResults_NeedDataSource"
            OnItemDataBound="grdResults_ItemDataBound" OnItemEvent="grdResults_ItemEvent"
            VirtualItemCount="999999" GroupingEnabled="False" >
            <ExportSettings>
                <Pdf PaperSize="Letter" FontType="Subset"></Pdf>
                <Csv RowDelimiter="NewLine" ColumnDelimiter="Comma"></Csv>
            </ExportSettings>
            <MasterTableView CurrentResetPageIndexAction="SetPageIndexToFirst" Dir="LTR" Frame="Border"
                TableLayout="Auto" CommandItemDisplay="None" DataKeyNames="RecordNumber" VirtualItemCount="999999"
                AllowCustomPaging="true" EditMode="InPlace" PagerStyle-Position="TopAndBottom">
                <RowIndicatorColumn CurrentFilterFunction="NoFilter" FilterListOptions="VaryByDataType"
                    Visible="False">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
                </RowIndicatorColumn>
                <ExpandCollapseColumn CurrentFilterFunction="NoFilter" FilterListOptions="VaryByDataType"
                    Visible="False" Resizable="False">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
                </ExpandCollapseColumn>
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="StudentName.FullName" CurrentFilterFunction="NoFilter"
                        HeaderText="Preferred Name" UniqueName="Name" ReadOnly="true">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Grade" CurrentFilterFunction="NoFilter" HeaderText="Grade"
                        ReadOnly="true">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="KindergartenCalendar" UniqueName="KGCal" CurrentFilterFunction="NoFilter"
                        HeaderText="KG Calendar" Display="False" ReadOnly="true">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Current Year Teacher/Advisor" UniqueName="CurrentTchrID"
                        DataField="CurrentTeacherID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBoxTeacher" runat="server" Height="350px">
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NextTeacherID" UniqueName="NextTchrID" CurrentFilterFunction="NoFilter"
                        HeaderText="Prior Year Teacher/Advisor" ReadOnly="true">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </Columns>
                <EditFormSettings>
                    <EditColumn CurrentFilterFunction="NoFilter" FilterListOptions="VaryByDataType">
                    </EditColumn>
                    <PopUpSettings ScrollBars="None" />
                </EditFormSettings>
                <NoRecordsTemplate>
                    No Records Returned
                </NoRecordsTemplate>
                <PagerStyle Position="TopAndBottom" />
            </MasterTableView>
            <SortingSettings EnableSkinSortStyles="False" />
            <ClientSettings AllowColumnsReorder="true" ReorderColumnsOnClient="true" ColumnsReorderMethod="Reorder" Resizing-ShowRowIndicatorColumn="False">
                <Resizing  ResizeGridOnColumnResize="True"
                    AllowColumnResize="True"></Resizing>
            </ClientSettings>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
        <uc1:ActionBar ID="ActionBarBottom" runat="server" CancelVisible="True" ExportVisible="True"
            SaveVisible="True" Text="Assign Teacher/Advisor" HelpVisible="True" ExportURL="~/DataExport.aspx?frm=AssignTeacherAdvisor2"
            OnSaveClick="ActionBar_SaveClick" OnCancelClick="ActionBar_CancelClick" />
    </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderFooter" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Trying to also include the aspx.cs code, but it's too long...?

Comment: What paging do you guys use? Numeric? PrevNext?
A possibility would be to use a custom numeric with two buttons only (Previous and Next) then setup the CommandName to trigger the save.

In the original GridView there was a PageIndexChanging event that could be triggered as the user changed the page.

Comment: PrevNext.  I considered just saving without alerting the user, but was hoping for a bit more input from the user before saving on their behalf. I'm guessing the PageIndexChanging event has been obsolesced (Sp?) because that sounds exactly like what I'm looking for!  Does it make a difference if I'm using RadGrid? I will do some research into this.  I appreciate your response!